# Synergy+ multiple clients and multiple monitors on one client

Tags: multiple-monitors, synergy

Will Synergy recognize or allow four clients, one of which has 3 monitors for a total of 6 monitors?

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but how you configure it depends on the OS.  Under Windows, all attached monitors are treated as one "screen", so depending on the layout multiple screens may share an edge (so if you have two screens side by side, there is only one "top" edge.  If you want to split this so that moving up on either screen goes to a different monitor, you will need to edit the config file and use partial edges.)

Under Linux with Xinerama (or nVidia TwinView) this is the same, but if you use separate X11 screens (aka Zaphod mode, where you can't drag windows between monitors, and DISPLAY=:0.1, :0.2, etc.) then it behaves quite differently and you may need to run one instance of Synergy for each screen.

I'm not sure about a multi-monitor Mac, but I'm guessing it's the same as Windows and Linux with Xinerama.

This is assuming the monitors form a more-or-less complete rectangle with no gaps (e.g. all the screens are in a line.)  If the PC with three screens doesn't have them in a line (e.g. two side by side and one above) then it becomes much more complex and may not be possible to switch screens from every monitor edge you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

I use it with one Windows machine with 2 monitors, one Ubuntu machine with two monitors, and one Ubuntu machine with 1 monitor. I have added a 4th before, but didn't use it so got rid of it. So I believe you would be fine with that setup.

My Windows PC is the server, as setting up the server in linux is painful at best. (at least to me)

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you, what did you have to do to make it work, please?

Comment: I have completely discontinued using this setup as I have completely changed environments.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no limitations on Synergy's support; as long as you are able to adequately describe the layout in the configuration, its possible.  I ran the server on a dual-display iMac with a client being a triple-display Windows machine before, so I would guess that you'd be fine.

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you, what did you have to do to make it work, please?

Comment: That was 6 years, 4 jobs, and 7 setups ago. I just looked and while I have files from that machine, my synergy config wasn't among them. I do remember that back then the UIs weren't that great so I wrote the configs by hand. I would check out the synergy project's website; those guys do a pretty good job supporting users and answering questions.

Comment: thank you much for revisiting. I was struggling with this (still am, in spite of valid configs) and was a bit frustrated with all the "works for me" answers on this page. So I truly very much appreciate that you looked :)

Comment: which, rereading the original question, didn't ask for that specificity, so ever more thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done it before with non-asymmetric number of monitors, and it worked great!

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you, what did you have to do to make it work, please?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party (since we are still waiting on this (supposed to be coming soon)) BUT

What i did was set my monitors up vertically according to windows. this being the machine i planned to host from. I have three monitors for it set up in an L on its side. so with the windows settings, my computer thinks that the single monitor in the middle is below the other two.

My work macbook and the second monitor i have for it sit above and below each other which is to the right of my windows set up. using the docs in the link below (and a little bit of math to find the percent based off my one not identical monitor XD) i set it so when you exit parts of the screen you enter others so it behaves like they are set up the way the monitors are physically set up. i'll include a snippet of my config file.

https://symless.com/help-articles/monitor-positioning-support

```
section: links
    windowsTower:
        left(65, 100) = windowsTower(0, 35)
        right(0, 29) = windowsTower(65, 100)
        right(65, 100) = workMacbook(0, 50)
        right(30, 64) = workMacbook(51, 100)

    workMacbook:
        left(0, 50) = windowsTower(65, 100)
        left(51, 100) = windowsTower(30, 64)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I have gotten it to work on 3 monitors, two on an Ubuntu 12.04 host, and one on a Windows 10 host.

I'm using the Ubuntu host as the server because I am docking my Windows 10 Notebook for use with a monitor.

I first started with one monitor each, configured the Synergy server on my Ubuntu host like this:

```
     [Ubuntu Display 1] [ Windows 10 display]
```

Next, I plugged in a second monitor on my Ubuntu host. When I plugged it in, I noticed my display changed to this:

```
     [Ubuntu Display 2] [Ubuntu Display 1] [ Windows 10 display]
```

Oddly, I was only able to toggle between my Ubuntu displays - I could not access my Windows Display. The mouse would leave the right-hand side of Ubuntu Display 1, and enter on the far left of Ubuntu Display 2. I only had one instance of Synergy running and it was still configured with Ubuntu on the left and Windows on the right.

So, I simply swapped the cables on my monitors and then got:

```
     [Ubuntu Display 1] [Ubuntu Display 2] [ Windows 10 display]
```

While the mouse now left Ubuntu Display 1 and smoothly transitioned to Ubuntu Display 2, my Windows 10 desktop was still inaccessible.

Having read some of the comments above, out of sheer curiosity, I launched a second instance of Synergy on my Ubuntu Box (remember, I chose this as my server) and 'voila!' - now I am able to transition through all three displays the way I was hoping.

```
     [Ubuntu Display 1] [Ubuntu Display 2] [ Windows 10 display]
```

Keeping this in mind, I am thinking that you'll have to do the same on your setup, and run one instance for every additional screen you want to add.

While I really can't say if that will work, I was hoping that documenting this would help someone out.

cheers!

Comment: Personally have used Synergy with a linux and windows host (gentoo) with the linux box being the server, I didn't need to fire up extra instances of synergy to make it work. However, if you have 2 different linux instances then you will need an instance of synergy on each of them.